# Constructing queries with MongoEngine and Q throws InvalidQueryError

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I am trying to construct a simple `or` query using `MongoEngine` and the `django.db.models.Q` class.

My code (run from `./manage.py shell`) is:

```
from db.models import User
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(Q(username='foo') | Q(email='bar'))
```

My `models.py` is just

```
from mongoengine import *

class User(Document):
    username = StringField()
    email = StringField()
```

I have tried several different versions, and always get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 193, in filter
    return self.__call__(*q_objs, **query)
  File "venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 109, in __call__
    raise InvalidQueryError(msg)
InvalidQueryError: Not a query object: (OR: ('username', 'foo'), ('email', 'bar')). Did you intend to use key=value?
```

I'm using Python 2.7.6 with the following packages:

```
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.8
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
mongoengine==0.9.0
psycopg2==2.6
pymongo==2.8
static3==0.5.1
```

I am new to Python and Django, but this seems fairly simple. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that I was importing the wrong `Q` class. For `MongoEngine` it should be:

```
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q
```

Comment: visitor is fixed or model name ?

Comment: @KaushikMakwana, if I understand your question right, `visitor` is fixed here, not the model name.